# Find second highest highest query doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I could not figure out why my query does not work. The errors shows aggregate function have to use group by. I add "group by MAX(Salary)" which can not do the trick. Please help, thanks!

**Table:**

[image]

**Query**

```
SELECT Name, MAX(Salary)
FROM  PRACTICE.SALARY
WHERE Salary 
NOT IN (SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM  PRACTICE.SALARY);
```

Comment: Just curious where are you practicing your sql from ? Is it an online tutorial or something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use aggregate function you need to add non-aggregate columns in `group by`

```
SELECT Name, MAX(Salary)
FROM  PRACTICE.SALARY
WHERE Salary 
NOT IN (SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM  PRACTICE.SALARY)
GROUP BY Name
```

but If you only want to get second heigh `SALARY`, your query will get the wrong result because you `group by` for each `NAME` and get `MAX(Salary)` will get every Salary of Max from each `NAME` instead of the whole table.

I think you can use this query to get your expect result.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  Name VARCHAR(50),
  Salary int
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Lucy',2008);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('PETER',3000);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('K',1900);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('TOM',2015);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('MARK',3001);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT Name, Salary
FROM  PRACTICE.SALARY
WHERE Salary <> (SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM PRACTICE.SALARY)
ORDER BY Salary DESC 
LIMIT 1;

| Name  | Salary |
| ----- | ------ |
| PETER | 3000   |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5VMTtiDcae11YqS1oQH1SB/0)

Comment: D-Shih Hi, thanks, I understand how to use LIMIT to achieve the output but I could not figure out why my query does not work.

Comment: When you use aggregate function you need to add non-aggregate columns in `group by`

Comment: And your query will get the wrong result because you `group by` for each `NAME` .  I edit my answer hope can help you  @crazymind

Comment: D-Shih Thanks. I understand it now.